# How can we create suction, without the use of a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum

How is it possible to create suction without the use of a vacuum?

For example: As I understand, positive displacement pumps transport fluid by creating a vacuum at their inlet to draw in a distinct volume of fluid down the pressure gradient, before ejecting it under pressure, towards their outlet.

Centrifugal pumps also come under the heading 'vacuum pumps',  but do they actually create a vacuum? It seems the definition of a vacuum is often disputed in this context.

Is it possible to design a suction pump that does not need to create a vacuum?

Thanks.

Comment: https://youtu.be/iA6enVQvNgw

Comment: This video might help:)

Answer (score 0):

Suction means you have a difference of pressure on the two ends of a pipe, so you don't need vacuum but just lower pressure, for example if you suck at a straw to get liquid to your mouth. But of cause you can transport liquids upwards without "suction". So maybe you have to say more exactly what you want.